# How can I install BASS audio libraries on VS 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include-path, bass

I'm working on a project using OpenCV and Visual Studio 2010. I'm having problems installing BASS audio libraries on VS 2010. I downloaded [these win32 libraries](http://www.un4seen.com/)

I added the `bass.lib` file to the linker input, and I also added the path to the .lib file (which is `C:\bass24\c`) in Additional Library Directories (in the linker section) and the `#include "bass.h"` in my .cpp file. This is the same thing you do with OpenCV files or any external files, the only difference is that I don't know what to put in *C/C++-> Additional Include Directories* (it already has `C:\opencv\build\include` for OpenCV in it). Does anyone know what to put there?

VS 2010 gives me this problem:

```
Error 1error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bass.h': No such file or directory
```

P.S.: I'm working on a sonification project where I have to track a colored object from my camera and have to play music if that object moves in different positions. I want to use BASS because it is possible to use the multispeaker option (play music on the right speaker if the object moves right and so on).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure that you did. The question still doesn't show an accepted answer. Please click the checkmark to the left of my answer (underneath the Upvote/Downvote arrows). I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I did it yesterday, but you are right it hadn't turned green. Sorry!!! Did it know ;)

Comment: Now it shows up as being answered! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2010 should know where the necessary library files are (based on your description), but you are forgetting to tell it where the `bass.h` file is.

In `C/C++` -> `Additional Include Directories`, add the directory `C:\bass24\C` because that is where the `bass.h` file is.

Comment: Thank you Derek! Now it works... the funny thing is that I tried that several times and it didn't work. But now it does... WEIRD! Anyway thank you very much!! :)